# expose VPN IP to External IP

Tags: vpn, routing, windows-server-2012

I have setup a VPN on a windows server 2012, I have several machines at multiple locations, (ie: laptop/workstation etc..).

What I need is to be able to connect to the VPN from anywhere and would be able to access the http/mysql/ssh through the external ip's.

My VPN connects just fine but i have no idea how to routes traffic/ports in/out from the external ip to the internal VPN IP.

Comment: Howdy!  Your question doesn't make much sense as-is.  "and end up with the same public ip." VPN's don't give out public IPs, they give out private IPs from the network they are hosted on. you also don't actually seem to be asking  question.  Perhaps edit your question to include a detailed scenario you're trying to accomplish (what "traffic"?, which "ports"?), and include what you've tried already, and what the results were.  Also, perhaps include details about your chosen VPN type/configuration.

Comment: In general though, if you used RRAS in Windows Server to setup the VPN, then note the first R stands for ROUTING, which should be a clue that that is where you would set up your routing, especially for the "RA" part of RRAS (Remote Access).  Head there, and if you get stuck, come back with specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: thanks for your responses, Does this makes sense now? "What I need is to be able to connect to the VPN from anywhere and would be able to access the http/mysql/ssh through the external ip's."

Comment: Unfortunately, not really.  If you create a VPN connection to the LAN where the servers are, you would then be part of that LAN, why would you be trying to access the servers via external IPs, when the internal ones are now in the same network as you? If you have a VPN connection established to a LAN, and you have split-tunnelling configured (so that ALL your internet requests don't try to go over the VPN), then accessing the External IP's would work exactly as it would if you had NO VPN in place.  If you're on a VPN to the LAN the servers are on, why not use the INTERNAL IPs to contact them?

Comment: Let me explain it more: I'm web developer, my machine (laptop or workstation), each has apache/mysql servers, sometimes i need external services like facebook api or others to be able to access my local machines (for testing purposes). The Windows server that has the VPN is on Amazon Instance. I would like my machines to be able to be exposed through a fixed ip regardless of the location/ or  from where i'm connecting.

Comment: Please edit the info in your comments into your question.  Maybe also consider spending the 5-15 minutes to actually drawing a network diagram showing where everything is with respect to each other.  In any case the answer almost certainly is about properly configuring your routes.  Without a detailed network description or diagram, I doubt anyone can tell you what routes you need.